# Is it possible to change the Android NFC tag scan interval?

Tags: android, nfc

What I gather from the [official Android docs on NFC](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html), the entire NFC tag scanning procedure (in reader mode) is handled by the OS. Basically, the OS says *'I'll let you know once I see a tag that interests you'* and there seems to be no way to influence how that works, even when a dedicated app is in the foreground.

The reason I am asking is because a quick test revealed that different Android hardware seems to scan at different intervals switching between short blips and active scans, suggesting that this might be configurable after all.

Is it somehow possible to affect the scan interval? For example, if the app is open or the device is rooted? Or is the scan interval even dictated by the NFC chip, so the OS has no influence at all?